# Locale with Android

Tags: android, localization, locale

I have an application developed in android(google 2.2 Api  level 8 ). There is a requirement about the application that we need to provide Locale feature.

Is it possible to do this ? OR if it is possible please provide me some examples so that i can understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this article for information on internationalization and localization: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html